# allow background mode, but terminate conditionally?

Tags: iphone, background, terminate

I'm setting "Application does not run in background" to NO

which means, it can go background and resumed later.

I'm putting some code in "applicationDidEnterBackground", 
and I would like to force quit the app when desirable. (when there's nothing to do in background.)

I read 'exit' is not recommended.
Can I post a message which will result in something like applicationWillTerminate maybe?

- Edit

Let me clarify why I would want that,
I want my app to run background when it's downloading something.. via beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler
But if user isn't downloading anything, I can safely quit the application.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you wan't to quit your app? Can't you just reset the app to the point you want? Like if a condition is met then call `popToRootViewController` on some `UINavigationController.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about this.

If you have work to do in the background and you set up a background task then it'll run for as long as it needs and execute its handler when done.

What you don't seem to be aware of is that if you have nothing to do in the background, your app is simply suspended and in fact does not run.

As this is the case, there's nothing you need to do, quitting the app won't gain you anything that you don't already get with suspension.

Comment: Jasarien: thanks for reply, I'd like to close the connection to my server if applicable.

Comment: You can do that in the `applicationWillEnterBackground:` method.

Comment: Jasarien: you mean, applicationWillResignActive ? .. there seems to be no applicationWillEnterBackground. I've tried applicationWillResignActive. Problem is, closing connection operation takes about 1-2 sec in my app. Sometimes, it successfully closes and sometimes it doesn't because time allowed between applicaitonWillResignActive to actually going to background seems too short.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's `applicationDidEnterBackground:` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW20

Answer (score 1):

The general Apple approach on iOS is that applications should never terminate themselves, for any reason.

It's important to understand that when your application is 'running' in the background, it's not really running: the 'Application does not run in background' key is basically there to ensure backwards compatibility with applications built for iOS 3 and lower, which tend to make certain assumptions about how the user will enter the app. There are very few reasons why a new app wouldn't support it.

Basically, don't bother: I suppose you could technically call `exit()`, but Apple will hate you for it, and it's bad style for the platform.